# Problem with PHP extension during upgrage Magento to 2.2.8

Tags: php, nginx, magento2

I have a problem when updating magento from version 2.2.5 to 2.2.8

```
  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I have added these extensions, but they are still not visible.

```
/etc/php/7.1/mods-available$ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 74 maj 31 13:43 calendar.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71 maj 31 13:43 ctype.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66 maj 31 13:43 dom.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 70 maj 31 13:43 exif.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 74 maj 31 13:43 fileinfo.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69 maj 31 13:43 ftp.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 64 maj 31 13:43 gd.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73 maj 31 13:43 gettext.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71 maj 31 13:43 iconv.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68 maj 31 13:43 intl.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68 maj 31 13:43 json.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 76 maj 31 13:43 mbstring.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 79 maj 31 13:43 opcache.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69 maj 31 13:43 pdo.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 70 maj 31 13:43 phar.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71 maj 31 13:43 posix.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 76 maj 31 13:43 readline.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71 maj 31 13:43 shmop.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72 maj 31 13:43 simplexml.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73 maj 31 13:43 sockets.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73 maj 31 13:43 sysvmsg.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73 maj 31 13:43 sysvsem.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73 maj 31 13:43 sysvshm.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 75 maj 31 13:43 tokenizer.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67 maj 31 13:43 wddx.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66 maj 31 13:43 xml.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72 maj 31 13:43 xmlreader.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72 maj 31 13:43 xmlwriter.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66 maj 31 13:43 xsl.ini
```

I uninstalled PHP and installed it again, but it does not give anything. I changed in php.ini but it also did not help. Does anyone have an idea what else I can try to do? I will be grateful for all kinds of tips

Comment: Those are the ini config files, not the extensions. Make sure you install/configure PHP with the required extensions. How did you install PHP? And which OS are you using?

Comment: @aynber I have Ubuntu 18 and installed normally via sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-intl etc ..

Comment: Well, based on your output above, you are enabling the extensions for the PHP cli client and not mod_php or fpm.  If you expect these changes to be refelected on your web-server, you need to enable the extensions in the other respective folder.  Be sure to restart the service using php.